# Estou tendo um problema com meu programa em c++

Tags: c++

estou tendo um erro executando esse codigo aqui:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int main (void) {
  char ent[7];
  char senha[7];
  printf("digite a senha: ");
  scanf("%s",&ent);
  printf("digite a senha novamente: ");
  scanf("%s",&senha);
  if (ent==senha){
     printf("foi");
  }
  else
  {
     printf("nao foi");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

por algum motivo naquele if aparece como se a variavel ent fosse diferente da variavel senha
com certeza deve ser algo bobo que eu devo ter esquecido,alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Você não está comparando duas string e sim dois arrays de caracteres. Para isso você pode usar a função strcomp():

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
  char ent[7];
  char senha[7];
  printf("digite a senha: ");
  scanf("%s",&ent);
  printf("digite a senha novamente: ");
  scanf("%s",&senha);
  if (strcmp(ent,senha) == 0){
     printf("foi");
  }
  else
  {
     printf("nao foi");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado cara,eu sei que ja faz um tempinho mas mesmo assim voce ajudou bastante agradeco muito a pessoas como voce dispostas a ajudarem